# How are neural nets combined to form intelligent systems?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

Self-driving cars, arms that can learn ow to pick up objects, machines that can have conversations, etc.  I understand how neural nets work.  But I really don't know much about how neural nets are combined to form intelligent systems.  Is it all rule-based above a few base nets for tasks like e.g. image recognition?  Or are there meta-nets that do deep learning on the outputs from base nets?

Things to read/references would be super-helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Neural networks can be combined together in a variety of ways. One promising direction is [Mixture-of-Experts (MoE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_of_experts), where different neural networks learn different parts of the problem space and are combined together.